# Why is this simple sum broken by compiler optimizations if I don't initialize the sum variable?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I am compiling C code into Matlab MEX files. Matlab turns on optimization by default (`-O2`). I have a simple normalization routine which is broken by this. By the time the `sum` is used here the value is only 0.995 when it should be 1.000:

```
int N = 10000;
double *w, sum;

for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    w[i] = 1.0/N;
}

...a couple unrelated operations...

for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
    sum += w[k];
}
for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
    w[k] = w[k]/sum;
}
```

When I compile with `-g` everything is just fine. So I figured this must not be up ISO standard. Then I discovered what I was missing:

```
sum = 0.0;
```

This fixes it. So I guess the compiler decided that I didn't care about the exact value of that variable since I didn't bother to initialize it properly? Would someone care to explain?

**Edit:** Yeah, I understand that it's undefined, but that doesn't explain why and how it affects the optimization of that sum. *How* does the compiler make an explicit decision that says, "Even though he's reading the sum, he must not care for the value." Does it keep track of undefined values somehow?

Comment: Your code has easily found undefined behaviour. Once the compiler finds undefined behaviour, it can and will do whatever it likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put yourself in the place of the compiler. You are implementing what the C standard mandates and guarantees.

So you compile the code, without optimization, and get something like this, compiling the code line by line without any analysis:

```
- add stack space for `sum`
...
- initialize k to 0
beginning_of_for:
- if k < N is not met, goto after_for
-   add w[k] to sum
-   increment k
-   goto beginning_of_for
after_for:
- ...
- (for example) print sum
```

which runs and initially `sum` happens to by chance contain the value 0. You don't see any strange behavior because you got lucky (or rather unlucky).

Now they tell you, the compiler, to optimize the code. You need to look around and squeeze out any unnecessary operation to save as much time and/or space. You go around and find out that sum is uninitialized. By standard, that means you are guaranteed you *won't* read from that variable later (even though the programmer turns out to have done so, but you don't care because the standard says you don't need to care). Furthermore, if you add an uninitialized value to some value, you get another uninitialized value that again you are guaranteed you *won't* read from it later.

So here's your assumption as a compiler:

```
- variable X is defined but not initialized
- some operations that don't read from X
- operation that writes to X a value that is not uninitialized
- operations that read from X
```

From your point of view, until X is initialized with a value that is not depending on other uninitialized values, then any read from X can give any arbitrary value, so you are allowed to just use 0 for example instead of actually reading from that value. What's more, any write that is based on uninitialized values can be discarded since the result is still an uninitialized value so it could be anything.

In other words, your previously unoptimized code:

```
- add stack space for `sum`
...
- initialize k to 0
beginning_of_for:
- if k < N is not met, goto after_for
-   add w[k] to sum
-   increment k
-   goto beginning_of_for
after_for:
- ...
- (for example) print sum
```

gets analyzed as follows:

```
Pass 1:

- add stack space for `sum`            [sum uninitialized]
...
- initialize k to 0                    [keep this as is]
beginning_of_for:
- if k < N is not met, goto after_for  [keep this as is]
-   add w[k] to sum                    [remove this line: sum is still uninitialized]
-   increment k                        [keep this as is]
-   goto beginning_of_for              [keep this as is]
after_for:
- ...
- (for example) print sum              [use 0 or whatever instead of sum]
```

which gives this:

```
- add stack space for `sum`
...
- initialize k to 0
beginning_of_for:
- if k < N is not met, goto after_for
-   increment k
-   goto beginning_of_for
after_for:
- ...
- (for example) print whatever
```

Next pass of optimization goes as this:

```
Pass 2:

- add stack space for `sum`            [sum uninitialized]
...
- initialize k to 0                    [replace 0 with N because of (1)]
beginning_of_for:
- if k < N is not met, goto after_for  [remove because of (1)]
-   increment k                        [remove because of (1)]
-   goto beginning_of_for              [remove because of (1)]
after_for:
- ...
- (for example) print whatever         [keep this as is]

(1) the for loop is empty.  `k` is `int` so it is guaranteed it will not overflow
    (Note: signed integer overflow is **undefined behavior** according to
    the standard), so the loop terminates with a single side effect: `k` reaches
    `N`.  So there is no point in actually looping.
```

Now your code becomes:

```
- add stack space for `sum`
...
- initialize k to N
- ...
- (for example) print whatever
```

In the final pass, you will get:

```
 Pass 3:

- add stack space for `sum`            [remove because sum is unused]
...
- initialize k to N                    [remove because k is unused]
- ...
- (for example) print whatever         [keep this as is]
```

Which means in the end you are left with:

```
- (for example) print whatever
```

And *that's* how optimization can lead to your whole code being thrown away because of uninitialized variable.

Comment: This answers my question, which is that optimizers are explicitly tracking uninitialized values. What happens here is not exactly the same as what I saw, but as we know all compilers and optimizers will be different. The key was that they will make synchronization decisions based on the initialization status of a variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _synchronization decision_, but yes optimizers do track uninitialized values and they are well allowed to remove code as I mentioned above.

Comment: Meaning that in my specific case the compiler parallelized the sum and decided that the results of the parallel sum didn't need to be completely finished before the next time `sum` was read... so it made no attempt to hold a lock on sum before reading. Pretty clever, actually.

Comment: @NeilTraft, parallelize is not the best word, since it often means trying to execute in separate threads. However, you _could_ think of the execution flow as mandated by the standard to be somewhat in parallel. Simply put, the standard mandates that if statement `A` depends on statement `B`, it is executed after, but if they are independent, they could be executed in any order. But it has a lot of details that don't fit here. You can always read [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)! Note that the link is to C11, which has a very different execution model.

Comment: Okay, so it wasn't parallelized I guess. Compiler optimizations don't go that far, eh? The standard doesn't allow for it, maybe. So it just changed the order and having some print statements in there was enough to (by chance) cause the order to be correct.

Comment: @NeilTraft, no compilers don't make the code multi-threaded. Optimizations like these are done per function and often functions are too small to worth parallelizing. There are facilities for this, like OpenMP, but still you need to be quite specific about it. In your particular example, without optimization the compiler usually doesn't reorder your code, so it happened to work simply because the point over the stack where `sum` was placed happened to be zero. With optimization, reordering or not, all that code is simply eliminated, since it is deemed useless.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, why would it expand both loops and then reorder those instructions arbitrarily? It must have been that `sum` was given a memory address that already contained a 0.995 floating point value (which is quite a coincidence since it's very close to the correct sum of 1.0). Hmmmm... but this is the only thing that really makes sense.